Why does creating a React/Vite app take so much time?
I'm trying to make a simple app with React but I'm stuck at the first step. It doesn't seem to do anything at all. Tried with both npx create-react-app and npm create vite@latest:

It's stuck on the loading animation for 10 hours, exact same with both Vite and React.
Using latest Node version.

Node 22.5? It's broken.

@jonrsharpe Thanks for sharing, that's good precedent to keep using LTS for regular tasks, especially FE

@jonrsharpe yes thank you! downgraded to LTS and app built instantly

As posted by @jonrsharpe , Node v22.5 is actualy broken, solution is to downgrade to LTS version

There are many possible reasons for npm install to take this long. Normally it takes only a few seconds, especially templates like create-react-app. What you should do is narrow down the issue:

Network Issues

If you have an unstable or slow internet connection, it will be slower. npm install downloads the JavaScript librarys from npm's package registry before storing it locally in your node_modules folder.
Try running ping google.com in the terminal.
Do you get an output like this?

You could also try speedtest.net. This will similarly tell you how fast your download speed is.

System Resources or Background Processes

Do you have other apps running? Sometimes this isn't a big deal, but you can try closing all other processes.

Node Modules

Sometimes the solution is as simple as deleting the node_modules folder. Once you do this, run npm install again.
I can't explain exactly why it would take 10 hours, but these are good places to start to help you isolate the issue. The fact that the same happened with Vite and React suggests one of the above issues.

what is the reason and purpose of deleting node_modules? these are dependencies for the react/vite app

@J.Doe I suggest deleting the folder and then rerunning the command because sometimes there's some corrupted file that's blocking the command. Sort of like restarting your computer or clearing your browser cache.

Creating a React or Vite app can sometimes take longer than expected for several reasons:

Network Speed

Node Modules

System Resources

Package Manager Issues

Temporary Files

Background Processes



so why is it taking over 10 hours?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
